# How to change font colors of amchart charts in bubble

Tags: javascript, amcharts, bubble.io

I'm trying to change the font color of charts on the bubble platform. I used the amcharts Javascript code that are available on this site: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/
I was able to change the font color of these two charts:[image: Example1]
But I was not able to change the font color of the legend of this graph. The caption that I would like to change the colors would be in the Fornecedor and Cliente field:[image: Example2]
And in this chart, I can't change the color of the field where the Inicial and Em Andamento text appears:
[image: Example3]

I found a code here on the stack, which I used to change the 2 graphs I got. The code would be this one:

```
xAxis.get("renderer").labels.template.adapters.add("fill", (fill, target) => { 
  if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.dataContext) {
    let category = target.dataItem.dataContext.category;
      
    if (category === "Ativo") {
      return "#868686";
    } else if (category === "Pendente") {
      return "#868686";
    } else {
      return "#868686";
    }
  }
    
  return fill;
});
```

I appreciate all the help!